# Datatables - Get sorted row order

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the DataTables plugin for JQuery. I need to get the clicked row's POSITION in the table after the ordering has been applied. For example if we have a table like this:

```
key     value
1       one
2       two
3       three
```

If I click on the key 2, it should return the second position. If the table gets reordered and displays like this:

```
key     value
2       two
1       one
3       three
```

If I click on the key 2 again, I expect it to return the first position. I have tried looking at the documentation and all over the internet for this and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Can you provide a real working example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to get table row index after sorting.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
   var index = table.rows( { order: 'applied' } ).nodes().indexOf(this);
   alert(index);
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tvvLo729/) for code and demonstration.